# What display cables and adapters should I use to connect a second monitor to GTX670?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi, cable

I searched a lot and now I'm just confused with all those M/M, F/F, F/M cables.

I have a GTX670 videocard with jacks DVI, DVI, HDMI, and DisplayPort:

[image]

The bottom-right DVI (with "plus") is used for my main monitor "Dell U2412M". Here are my main monitor jacks:

[image: DP, DVI, VGA]

I want to simultaneously connect another smaller monitor which only has VGA input.

I read on forums that the videocard doesn't support using analog and digital outputs simultaneously

What adapters and cables do I have to use? Which should be M/M, F/F, M/F? Will it work if my monitors have different resolutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *should* be able to use both - I'm pretty sure I've done it before.

You do *not* want to be using the bottom DVI connector in this setup since that's essentially your only analog port. Its DVI-I (which as you'll see can be broken out into VGA)

The top DVI connector (that's DVI-D) would be a better option for the monitor that's currently using DVI.

In your shoes, I'd dig out the DVI-I -> VGA converter that should have come with your card. This will have a male DVI-I connector (or a DVI-A one. Dosen't really matter here) and a female VGA port.  Plug it into the bottom DVI port, plug one end of the VGA cable on the female vga port and plug the VGA only monitor into it.  It would look like this

[image]

Take a DVI cable (both ends are the same and should be a male connector with a - _, and plug it into the top port and your Dell monitor. It should just work. Alternately you can use a full size display port cable (If you have one. Not much difference at these resolutions).

While there's a few oddities (like scaling) with dissimilar monitors, there's no reason it shouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/371378-33-gettings-monitors-work you can sue **one** analog signal at a time.
That would fit your requirements as you only have 2 monitors (one digital and one analog).

You also need a DVI-**I** to VGA connector, because DVI-**D** does not support analog signals. 
The cable needs to be M/M (male to male), but always check using pictures of the adapter and the connector of your monitor.

[image: DVI-I vs. DVI-D]
Here is a picture to tell which DVI connector is **D** (digital) and which one is **I**.